# BottomNavigationView и Fragment. Как сохранить состояние?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, bottom-navigation-view

Есть BottomNavigationView и 3 Fragment'а. Фрагмент "Home" содержит ScrollView. При переключении на другие фрагменты, и возвращаясь, состояние сбрасывается к начальному. Т.е. если проскролить до конца, а затем вернуться в фрагмент "Home", ScrollView будет отображаться с самого начала. Как сохранить состояние?

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView mainBottomNavigation;
    Fragment homeFragment;
    Fragment favouriteFragment;
    Fragment musicFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mainBottomNavigation = findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationView);
        homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        favouriteFragment = new FavouriteFragment();
        musicFragment = new MusicFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerMain, homeFragment).commit();

        mainBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.homeItem) {
                showFragment(homeFragment);
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.favourite) {
                showFragment(favouriteFragment);
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.music) {
                showFragment(musicFragment);
            }
            return true;
        });
    }

    private void showFragment(Fragment currentFragment) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerMain, currentFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

HomeFragment

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    private int count = 0;
    TextView textView;
    boolean isCreated = false;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        textView = view.findViewById(R.id.homeTextView);
        Button increment = view.findViewById(R.id.increment);

        if (!isCreated) {
            textView.setText("Home Fragment");
        } else {
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(count));
        }
        increment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            count++;
            textView.setText(count + " ");
        });
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        isCreated = true;
    }
}
```

FavouriteFragment

```
public class FavouriteFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.favourite_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

MusicFragment

```
public class MusicFragment extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_fragment, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 0):

Для ваших целей я думаю подойдёт SharedPreferences. Введите какие-то порядковые номера для ваших фрагментов например, или любую другую идентификацию чтобы можно их было как-то различать. Запись переменной я бы советовал осуществлять в селекторе нижнего меню, для этого вынесем сохранение в отдельный метод:

```
private void savePos(Integer pos){
    SharedPreferences mSettings = getSharedPreferences("app_data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    editor.putInt("frag_id", pos); // например будем писать порядковый номер
    editor.apply();

}
```

Который будем вызывать тут:

```
mainBottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(item -> {
            if (item.getItemId() == R.id.homeItem) {
                savePos(0);
                showFragment(homeFragment);
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.favourite) {
                showFragment(favouriteFragment);
            } else if (item.getItemId() == R.id.music) {
                showFragment(musicFragment);
            }
            return true;
        });
```

и дальше в методе onCreate вашей активности считываем данную переменную:

```
Integer fragId = mSettings.getInt("frag_id", 0);
```

После получения кидаем это все в какой-то switch-case например и делаем выбор нижнего меню. Вот [туториал по работе с SP](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/sharedpreferences.php) и [документация](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но думаю вы не совсем верно поняли вопрос. В моём случае фрагменты, при переключении проходят жизненный цикл от onCreateView до onDestroy. Соответственно, после переключения фрагмент Home пересоздается и отображается с самого верха. Мне нужно сохранить положение, где скролинг был остановлен. Ваш вариант не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать создать final массив из экземпляров ваших фрагментов [image: вот так]

Comment: а затем обращаться в массив по индексу нужного фрагмента через ваш метод showFragment()

Comment: нагляднее будет добавить этот фрагмент кода в виде текста, а не скриншота

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120/189027